# Hat shown in Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, WordPress Answers but not shown in Drupal Answers?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

I am using the L'chaim hat which is shown on all my Stack Exchange sites, such as Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, WordPress answers etc.. But it is not shown on Drupal Answers.

Do I have to do something to make the hat appear on my Drupal Answers account?

Comment: Did you opt-in to it on Drupal answers? Or opt-out (I hate hats link in the snowflake dropdown)?

Comment: What I need to opt?

Comment: On some sites you do. Though, you may have opted out.

Comment: But other sites like worpress answers,meta stackoverflow are shown hat without opt it why?

Comment: Stack Overflow because of performance. Other sites - I believe it is what their mods wanted.

Comment: Then in any site I choose "I hate hat" option all my hats are hide. What about this option?

Comment: If you "hate hats" then surely you don't want "any" to be shown?

Comment: @James if I love them all these are not shown that is my question.

Comment: @Oded Did Drupal opt in as a site?

Comment: [Yes](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/winter-bash-2013) @slugster.

Comment: Just click "wear hat" on any site where your hats appear, then they'll be visible on Drupal as well.